# Regarding permissions of CIFS shares.

Tags: netapp

We recently changed the domain of our filer due to this few users have lost permissions to their CIFS shares. Is there a way to get the *fsecurity show* output from some config file, so that i can proactively check for the changes before and after domain change.

Answer (score 0):

There's no saved config for permissions. The best you might manage is - if you've snapshot copes, the snapshots *may* have different permissions. It depends if they're inherited or share level permissions though.